# Is there a way to determine if an iPhone / iPad app is installed?

Tags: iphone, browser, ipad

Looking for code that would run in a browser (Safari) to determine if a certain iphone app was installed on a users device (iphone, ipad or ipod touch). The end goal is dynamically display messaging on a site to instruct the user to go install the app.

Answer (score 3):

No way Apple will ever open up such functionality :) (and it does not exist right now)

Answer (score 3):

This would be a significant privacy issue, Apple would not permit it.