# Find App installed or not

Tags: iphone

How to find the app is installed in device.

Comment: Do you have a specific application in mind? Or just a general one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to determine if an iPhone / iPad app is installed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751640/is-there-a-way-to-determine-if-an-iphone-ipad-app-is-installed)

Answer (score 4):

If you look for an application that registers a URL scheme that it can open, then you can check for the presence of that app using the UIApplication -canOpenURL: method, as documented here: [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW50) ; otherwise it is not possible normally from the SDK.