# How to detect if Browser is (not) iPhone, iPad or iPod in PHP?

Tags: php, iphone, ipad, browser

I want to run some code if the user is not using an apple mobile device browser (iphone, ipad or ipod).

I tried the following but I have no idea if it works:

```
<?php
if(!strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone') || !strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPod') || !strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPad')) 
{
     // user is not on an iPhone, iPad, or iPod device so execute code
}
?>
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: afaik, the code you posted will work - is there some reason you didn't TIAS before asking?

Comment: Hope that you really do care about the device and aren't really looking for Mobile Safari.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to determine if an iPhone / iPad app is installed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751640/is-there-a-way-to-determine-if-an-iphone-ipad-app-is-installed) - This might at least partially answer your question and offers more information.

Answer (score 4):

I have used [*php-mobile-detect*](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/) and it works very nicely. Can detect all kinds of devices!

> Mobile_Detect is a simple PHP class for easy detection of the most popular mobile platforms: Android, iPhone, Blackberry, Opera Mini, Palm, Windows Mobile, as well as generic ones.

Answer (score 0):

i use this function

```
if(!function_exists("iOSCheker")) {
    function iOSCheker($var1,$var2) {
        if (ereg('iPhone',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) || ereg('iPod',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) || ereg('iPad',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) { 
            echo $var1;
        } else {
            echo $var2;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: [`ereg` is depercated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700806/function-eregi-is-deprecated).