# Detect if an app is installed on iPad or iPhone (iOS6 & iOS7)

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, ipad, mobile-safari

I'm using Apple's [smart app banner](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html) to promote my app on the site, however this does not work on other browsers (ie. Chrome) on iPad or iPhone.

Therefore I've implemented a JS plugin call [Smart App Banner](https://github.com/ijason/Smart-App-Banners), but in iOS7 the native banner is able to detect the app is installed and open it rather than going to the app store, would it be possible to do the same using JS and check if an app is installed and open the app rather than going to the app store?

Comment: Please check this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751640/is-there-a-way-to-determine-if-an-iphone-ipad-app-is-installed?rq=1

Comment: @PiyushDubey Yes. Closing as it's duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to know whether the app is installed or not using a simple javascript call. At Branch Metrics we've built a customizable app download banner from scratch. Let me describe one basic approach you could take, then I'll describe the more advanced version.

**Simple version**

Have a banner with a button that says "view in app". That button should do two things when it is clicked:
1. Fire the URI scheme, but in an iframe to hide the error message
2. Use setTimeout to redirect to the App Store or Play Store if the app is not installed.

In the body, have the following (this helps hide an ugly error message if firing the app's URI fails):

```
<iframe id="l" width="1" height="1" style="visibility:hidden"></iframe>
```

Then when the user taps on the button, fire off the following script:

```
// Deep link to your app goes here
document.getElementById("l").src = "my_app://";

setTimeout(function() {
    // Link to the App Store should go here -- only fires if deep link fails                
    window.location = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my.app/id123456789?ls=1&mt=8";
}, 500);
```

The downsides to this are that you don't know whether the app is installed so the button needs to say something generic like "view in app", rather than specifically "install" or "open" depending on whether the user has the app.

**Hard version (don't do this)**

If you want to know, when the page loads, whether the user has the app, you will need to:

1. Keep a cookie in the browser tied to this user
2. Take a digital fingerprint of the user (IP address, OS, OS version, screen size, etc.) and send it to your backend. Associate this with the cookie.
3. When the user opens your app, send up the same digital fingerprint. Your backend can match this to the browser-based digital fingerprint and note that this user/cookie has the app
4. On subsequent visits to your website (which has the banner), the server returning the page should use the cookie to lookup whether the user has the app. If so, return a banner with text "open". If not, return a banner with text "install."

This is non-trivial but certainly doable. The simple version can be done in minutes (you just need to figure out what you want your banner to look like) whereas the hard version will require backend and app modifications and endless testing and tweaking to get the digital fingerprinting and matching correct. We've been working on this for a year at Branch and know how painful it is.

Hopefully this gives you some workable solutions for a smart app banner.